# plot() vs curve() in R: why can curve() not accept an inline defined function

Tags: r

Why do plot() & curve() behave differently in this context? plot() seems to do ok with defining a function in place. Whereas curve() seems to not like it:

```
> plot(function(x) sin(x), 0,3.14)
> plot(sin, 0,3.14)
> 
> curve(sin, col="red",add=T)
> curve(function(x) sin(x), col="red",add=T)
Error in curve(function(x) sin(x), col = "red", add = T) : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

Is this just an inconsistency or is there a deeper way to understand this?

Can one not always use an inline definition of a function wherever one can use a named function?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `plot.function`-function. Use `methods(plot)` to see that it is visible and its code can be seen with:

```
 plot.function
```

It sends its first argument to `curve` and then positionally matches any additional arguments up to 4 in number as `from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab`. Any further arguments must match by name with those of `curve`

The `curve`-function does not have any methods, so giving it a function-object as first argument fails. I sympathize with this difficulty you are experiencing, but the `?curve` help page doesn't actually say that you can give a function as a first argument, rather saying you can give an R-name, i.e an expression(in the loose sense of the word) that can be looked up in the symbol table with a function as its value. When talking about the R language, the terms `name` and `symbol` are synonymous.